# sql order by timestamp, some rows missing

Tags: sql

I am trying to order results by timestamp but, when there is a duplicate timestamp a result is missed out and it gets one less. I don't like getting one less as It's not suppose to happen like that.

***qr.d column is a timestamp (example: 2013-08-28 23:04:47)***

***qr.id is a unique int***

I've tried to order things by qr.d but I get only ***14*** results. when I order things by qr.d,qr.id I still get only ***14*** results. when I order things only by qr.id I get ***15*** results.

Here is my sql:

```
SELECT login.pid,qr.id,qr.u,qr.d
FROM login 
LEFT JOIN qr ON login.pid=qr.u 
ORDER BY qr.d,qr.id LIMIT 0,15
```

Why is it behaving as if I have asked for UNIQUE results?

Comment: Consider uploading your problem to sql fiddle. It'll be a lot easier for us

Comment: never knew it existed... one sec trying to learn how to use it...

Comment: In short, you're supposed to create and fill your schema in the left panel, and perform queries in the right.

Comment: this tool is not giving me much confidence mate, it keeps telling me my column count does not match where as it shouldn't have to as id auto increments and d (timestamp) should just recognise the current time.

Comment: I'm guessing you're talking about when you insert data... Did you remember to define the INCREMENT on this column? It's a really useful site so don't give up so fast

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36559/discussion-between-itay-and-ben-muircroft)

Comment: @BenMuircroft Could you solve this?